# Create new document from Google form and add to a new folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms, google-docs-api

I have a Google script triggered on submission of a form. It creates a new doc based on a template with certain variables in-filled from answers in the form.

I also have a folder created on the form submission.

The trouble I am having is creating the newly created doc within the newly created folder. Looking for some help merging the two scripts that work on their own to acheive this.

**Creating a folder on form submission:**

```
function createChannelFolder() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Certifications");
var ChannelName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(), 2).getValue(); 
var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDERID");
return newFolder=parentFolder.createFolder(ChannelName);
  
}
```

**Creating a document on form submission**

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Channel = e.values[1];
  var Name = e.values[2];;
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID'); 
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(Channel + ',' + Name, folder); 
  var newId = copy.getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId); 

  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', Timestamp); 
  body.replaceText('{{Channel}}', Channel);  
  body.replaceText('{{Name}}', Name);
         
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You need to call `createChannelFolder()` inside
  `autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e)`.
- just return the folder object within `createChannelFolder()`:

  `return parentFolder.createFolder(ChannelName);`

---

### Solution:

Here is `autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e)`:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Channel = e.values[1];
  var Name = e.values[2];;
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID'); 
  
  var folder = createChannelFolder(); // 1st modification point
  var copy = file.makeCopy(Channel + ',' + Name, folder); 
  var newId = copy.getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId); 

  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', Timestamp); 
  body.replaceText('{{Channel}}', Channel);  
  body.replaceText('{{Name}}', Name);
         
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

and here is `createChannelFolder()`:

```
function createChannelFolder() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Certifications");
var ChannelName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(), 2).getValue(); 
var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDERID");
return parentFolder.createFolder(ChannelName); // 2nd modification point
  
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly, only outstanding issue is that two folders are created with one containing the document, any ideas?